# How I can Delete a row in Access with its ID number(autonumber)? in C#

Tags: c#, types, autonumber

coulmn count is autonumber
I want to Delete a row Where 
`"Where(Table1.count)='" + count1 + "'";`
but I dont know what should be the type of count1 !!!
When I use 
`"Where(Table1.count)=9";` 
I dont have any problem & the row with id numbr 9 will be deleted
But my id number is changeable!!!
the full code is

```
int count1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        OleDbCommand MyOleDbComm2 = new OleDbCommand();
        ObjConn2.Open();
        MyOleDbComm2.CommandText =
            MyOleDbComm2.CommandText =
            "DELETE FROM Table1 " +
            "Where(Table1.count)='" + count1 + "'";
        MyOleDbComm2.Connection = ObjConn2;
        MyOleDbComm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ObjConn2.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should keep its type to whatever is the type of **id column** in database.

Though in your case here if you want to use `count1` only in this query you can keep it string/int. I also see a problem in your query. it should be

```
"DELETE FROM Table1 Where(Table1.count)=" + count1; //note i have removed single quotes
```

unless your id column is string in database.

Comment: what have you changed?